# How to count the number of lines per file in a directory, then create summary of number of files with n lines

Tags: bash, awk, printf, wc, associative-array

I'm trying to create a summary of how many files in a directory have n number of lines in them. I'm using `wc -l * | sort` to print out the number of lines against the name of each file. What I'm trying to achieve is a summary of the directory which would produce:

```
56 5
60 6
3  7
```

etc, where the first column represents number of files and the second represents number of lines.

I've looked at an awk command `awk 'END{print NR}' directory/*` which returns the number of lines in the entire directory. I have considered a `printf` solution to format the `wc -l` output . Any assistance would be greatly greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your "wc -l *" counts the lines in the way you need, so e.g. no funny filenames, you can then just use uniq -c to do the counting for you. The head -n -1 is to get rid of the "total" line at the end:

```
wc -l *|head -n -1|sort|awk '{print $1}'|uniq -c
```

Comment: Note that doesn't work if there's only one non-hidden file in the current directory as the `total` line is then not printed. Also note that `head -n -1` is not standard. `wc -l ./* | awk '/\//{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c` would address those issues and work with arbitrary file names (even *funny* ones) (same approach as in my answer except non-recursive).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
find . -type f -print0 | gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS = "\0"
    while ((getline < "-") > 0) ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
    if (ARGC == 1) exit
    RS = "\n"
  }
  ENDFILE {count[FNR]++}
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (i in count) print count[i], i
  }'
```

Where we set the list of files to process in the BEGIN statement by reading it NUL-delimited from `find -print0`'s output.

Or the same with `perl` (with the caveat that empty files are ignored):

```
find . -type f -print0 | perl -0 -ne '
  BEGIN{@ARGV = <STDIN>; $/ = "\n"}
  if (eof) {$count{$.}++; close ARGV}
  END {print "$count{$_} $_\n" for sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count}'
```

Note that those count the number of lines, delimited or not while `wc -l` counts the number of newline characters. That makes a difference for instance for a file created with `printf foo > file` where `wc -l` would report 0 but `perl`/`gawk` 1.

Using `wc`, POSIXly, you could do:

```
find .//. -type f -exec wc -l {} + | LC_ALL=C awk '
  /\/\// {count[$1]++}
  END {for (i in count) print count[i], i}' | sort -k2n
```

By using `.//.`, we can tell on which line a file path starts in the output of `wc` (since `//` cannot occur anywhere else) and the line count will be the first field of that line, so we can reliably process file paths containing newline characters. That also skips the `total` line that `wc` invocations that are passed more than one argument print at the end as it doesn't contain `//`.

With GNU `grep` or compatible, you can also do:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -rch '^' . | sort -n | uniq -c
```

We're `c`ounting the number of lines that match `^`, that is that have a beginning, so all the lines, in all the files `r`ecursively in `.`, `-h` to skip printing the file's name. `LC_ALL=C` to not bother decoding the content as text (it's likely GNU `grep` at least would optimise out that decoding anyway given that regexp).

Note that all those also count hidden files.

To skip them, you can change the `find` command to:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -print0
```

There's no equivalent with GNU `grep -r`, though you could drop the `-r` and have `find` pass the list of files to `grep`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -exec grep -ch {} +
```